# Proper SSH keys location for a system user?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have a system account with which I run a database (namely mongodb). By default it has no home. Now I'd like to trigger scp commands from that account, with ssh keys authentication to a remote server, to export backups.

Should I just create a /home/mongodb and /home/mongodb/.ssh folders manually to store the SSH keys, like the default for regular users ? Is it still considered a system account after that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `-i` option to SCP you can specify any SSH private key (that the user can read) as the "Identity File" -- this may obviate your question (you can put the key wherever you want, as long as it's readable by the MongoDB user and you specify it with `-i` :-)

---

Diving into the question you asked though, the **generic unix answer** to your question is to put them in the .ssh directory under the user's home directory.  To locate that home directory look in /etc/passwd (see the manpage for that file if you're unfamiliar with its format).

If as you noted the user has no home directory (it's set to something invalid, or `/`) you can create that user a home directory and update their account to point to the correct home directory (the tools to do this vary from system to system, however `vipw` is usually a good place to start).  This reduces it to the problem above.

As for what constitutes a "system account", this is a religious question.  In my environments "system accounts" have numeric UIDs lower than 1000 and their password locked out (encrypted password set to "*").
Other people will tell you that for it to be a "system account" it should have `nologin` as its shell, or that the home directory should be in a particular place (or nonexistent), or that *all* of these criteria must be met :-)

Answer (score 1):

It probably would be best to set up a regular user account, and just set their shell to notty, and use ssh-keygen -t rsa to set up the ssh folder permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Debian distribution, than every user that has no home in /home/user has it's home in /var/lib/user. There you can find, or create (if it doesn't exists already) directory .ssh/. I am not sure if that path is the same also for other distribution (centos,...).

Comment: This may or may not be true on other operating systems.  Setting the home directory of accounts who should have no home directory to `/nonexistent` (and not having that path exist :) is a common practice on BSD systems...

Comment: That's why I wrote how it should work on Debian, and that it can be different on other operating systems (as you mentioned in your comment).

Comment: Still, that seems like a pretty good place to put the home directory of a system user that needs one.